# Transitioning the overlap of multiple objects

Tags: mesh, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to fade an object's regular solid surface into its wireframe.

I've got as far as duplicating the object and deleting vertices until I'm left with an area of overlap.

[image]

Is it possible to render this in such a way that there is a smooth transition at the area of overlap? Maybe there is a better way to achieve this effect?

Another example:
[image]

Comment: What does "fade an object's regular solid surface into its wireframe" mean? You want to animate it as a diffuse and then it slowly turns transparent, showing the wireframe? There's a way to do that. What does "a smooth transition at the area of overlap" mean?

Comment: I just want a single frame render. The render I posted is of two hemispheres which overlap a little bit. I'd like the area where they overlap to be "blurred" such that instead of the solid surface ending and the wireframe starting, there is a "transition/fade" from surface to wireframe.

Comment: So you want it to be gradually more transparent on that last ring of faces till it fades to fully transparent?

Comment: That would probably achieve the look I'm going for, yeah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the compositor and different scenes. This method uses three scenes: one for the regular shaded sphere, one for the wireframe and one that we will use as a factor input to blend between the two. Maybe there are better ways to do this.

1. I am assuming you have you scene set up with a sphere, plane, and the lights.

   [image]
2. Rename the current scene to something like *sphere_shaded* to be able to differentiate it better form the other we will create

   [image]
3. Create a *Full Copy* of the scene and rename it to something like *sphere_wireframe*

   [image]
4. Make sure you are in the *sphere_wireframe* scene: Select the sphere and add a *Wireframe* Modifier to it

   [image]
5. Go back to the *sphere_shaded* scene and create another *Full Copy*, let's call it *sphere_fac*
6. In the *sphere_fac* scene delete everything besides the sphere and the camera
7. In the the same scene add a lamp, I will chose an area lamp but any other will do
8. Change the background of the scene to black

   - go the *World Panel* -> *Surface* -> *Color*

   [image]
9. Position the light so that half of the sphere visible to the camera is getting light and the other half is in the shadows.

   - To make this task easier you can got into the camera view and turn and set the viewport type to rendered

   [image]
10. Render out all scenes, <kbd>F12</kbd>
11. Switch to the *Node Editor* and switch to the compositing nodes. Enable *use nodes* and *backrdrop*

    [image]

    [image]
12. Add in the other render scenes

    - By default there should be one render scene already in the node view, duplicate it and form the name drop down choose the others.

    [image]
13. Add a *Color* -> *Mix* node

    - Fac: plug in *sphere_fac*
    - Image: *sphere_shaded*
    - Image: *sphere_wireframe*

    [image]
14. To get more control over the transition you can adjust the *sphere_fac* node a bit

    - RGB curves: good control, a little overkill I think for this
    - Brightness/Contrast: to simple
    - Color Ramp: simple, enough control

    I will use a Color Ramp in this case: *Converter* -> *Color Ramp* adjust the two slider on either side to your liking

    [image]

---

## Final Result

[image]

## Same technique with a point lamp

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. this lighting method will only work when it's a nice sphere. I'd like to actually do this on a more complex object.

Comment: @ajwood in that case you can use a simple gradient as an image for the effect.

Comment: I don't think a simple gradient would work. The boundary between shaded and wireframe could be any shape.

Answer (score 7):

According to what you illustrated, I would propose a non-compositing way by using modifiers only:

1. Enter **Edit Mode**, Select one face as where the transition starts, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > **Cursor to Selected** to snap cursor to that face;
2. Select all faces, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and search for **Sort Mesh Elements**, choose **Cursor Distance** in the popup menu, press <kbd>F6</kbd> and toggle *Reverse*;
3. Create a duplication for the original object, repeat the last two steps on it, just leave *Reverse* untoggled;
4. Add **Build** modifier to the original object, toggle *Reverse* in the modifier stack;
5. Add a **Wireframe** modifier and a **Build** modifier to the duplicated object, leave *Reverse* untoggled this time.

After tweaking the modifier settings a bit, you will simply get something like this when playing animation:

[image]

[**Example file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27776) FYI.

Comment: I see you would like the SMOOTH way here. In that case, you have to use nodes. Anyway, just wanna share with this trick, supposing it would be also useful for some cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same effect with the following material setup:

[image]

Detail of node setup:

[image]

If you want the blur to conform to the shape of the hole, put a black and white UV/image texture node in the factor slot of your mix shader instead. You will have to paint the texture yourself with texture painting or in photoshop, but once you have it UV mapped onto your object, it will achieve the effect you're looking for (I think).

See this, it tells you how to use an image mask as a mix factor for a material in cycles:
[Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/748#748)

Comment: This would be perfect if I could get a texture that measures the distance to the "edge" of the object (my vocabulary is hurting... "unclosed edge"?)