# How to create a material that is part solid, part transparent wireframe?

Tags: materials, wireframe

For a 3D rendering of an organ, I would like to make part of it a transparent wireframe so the contents become visible (similar to this [image](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/sahua/sahua0804/sahua080400036/2894308-cyber-apple-with-wireframe-all-is-editable-it-isn-t-mesh.jpg), only I would like to have a much smaller area as the transparent wireframe). Could anyone point me to a tutorial, our explain me a bit how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: I asked something similar a while back: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/transitioning-the-overlap-of-multiple-objects

Comment: This comment actually answered my question, thanks!

Comment: Thanks to ajwood, solution here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/transitioning-the-overlap-of-multiple-objects

Comment: Nice! I'd love to see the image you made, if you can share it!

Answer (score 0):

In Blender Internal render engine, you can use Freestyle. To enable freestyle - Go to the render panel and click freestyle - [image]

Then go to edit mode, select the edges that you want to render and press "Crtl+E"
and click "mark freestyle edge".
[image]

Then go to "Render Layers", click on the Line set that should be automaticly created and click only on "edge mark"
[image]

Then on the tab "freestyle line style", you have options for the lines.
[image]
Then you can click on render.
[image]