# How to change mix materials based on how much light they are receiving?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I'm currently trying to do Andrew Price's "Create a Realistic Earth Tutorial (http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-realistic-earth/#.VIRSTDGsXbU)", but in Cycles, and I am unable to change the texture based on how much light that part of the object is receiving. If you look at the second link, you'll see the effect Im trying to create - where the dark side displays city light. I should also add that I want to do this specifically with edited image textures.

My currently node setup is linked, everything works perfectly independently, but the nodes inside the red box are what seems to mess everything up. Thanks a lot for any help you can provide.

--

Here is my current node setup: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6nvrrgsnkopvg5/Earth%20Texture%20Help.jpg?dl=0

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/szojctfbxem0ep2/Earth-Day-Night-Science-Wallpaper.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The shader for the city lights should be of type [Emission](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Emission).

Comment: Not sure how to get that in a node, but you could use a technique like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7956/822).